# Laravel 7 routing

Tags: laravel

I have two statuses that are pending & completed. But when I click pending or completed links Laravel gives me URLs like this,

`http://website/post?pending`
`http://website/post?completed`

But I'm expecting URLs like this,

`http://website/post/pending`
`http://website/post/completed`

Here is my code

**web.php**

`Route::get('post/{status?}',['as' => 'post.status','uses' =>'PostController@status']);`

**PostController**

```
public function status($status= '', Request $request){
    if($status=="pending") {
        $posts = Post::where('status','pending')->get();
    }

    if($status=="completed") {
        $posts = Post::where('status','completed')->get();
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('*post/pending') ? ' active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{route('post', 'pending')}}" >
        {{ __('Pending') }}
    </a>
</li>

<li class="{{ request()->is('*post/completed') ? ' active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{route('post','completed')}}">
        {{ __('Completed') }}
    </a>
</li>
```

These two URLs,

`http://website/post/pending`
`http://website/post/completed`

working completely fine & gives me expected results when I manually entered them into the browser's searchbar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? I would assume that you are not generating the routes properly - how should Laravel guess where to put that second parameter of `route('post', 'pending')`? Have you checked how `route` should be called (as in: with an array as second parameter)?

Comment: Do you really need making status optional? post, post/.... should be different routes with different controllers or methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="{{route('post', 'pending')}}" > // this will create query string 
<a href="{{route('post', ['status'=>'pending'])}}" > // this will consider as param based url
```

You have to change your view code as below:

```
<li class="{{ request()->is('*post/pending') ? ' active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{route('post', ['status'=>'pending'])}}" >
        {{ __('Pending') }}
    </a>
</li>

<li class="{{ request()->is('*post/completed') ? ' active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{route('post', ['status'=>'completed'])}}" >
        {{ __('Completed') }}
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Now Laravel gives URL like this ```post?status=completed```

Comment: change your route as : Route::get('post/{status?}',['as' => 'post','uses' =>'PostController@status']);

Comment: How is it working? Isn't it suppose to use ```post.status```?

Comment: because you just use "post" so there was a mismatch. you defined post.status so in view you have to user "post.status" instead of "post"